# How to get to know RAM and CPU usage of any given process

Tags: go, cpu, ram

I am trying to create a Go program that can take any process name (e.g. calc.exe) and output the total RAM usage and CPU usage of the process at the moment.
I want it for Windows machine (but it would be better if the solution works on Linux machine as well -  which I doubt if same code will work at both)

I have been trying to do it using `syscall` but it seems it is not very helpful for Windows machine.

On internet I found `x/sys/windows` package may help. I have tried the given example, but it seems the type and method the example was suggesting (i have shown it in below sample code) is not even present in the library.

```
    pid := 14768

    // Open the process
    handle, _ := syscall.OpenProcess(syscall.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, uint32(pid))
    defer syscall.CloseHandle(handle)

    // Get the process's CPU usage
    var cpuUsage float64
    var creationTime, exitTime, kernelTime, userTime syscall.Filetime
    err = syscall.GetProcessTimes(handle, &creationTime, &exitTime, &kernelTime, &userTime)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error getting process CPU usage:", err)
        return
    }
    cpuUsage = float64(kernelTime.Nanoseconds()+userTime.Nanoseconds()) / float64(1e7)

    // Get the process's RAM usage
    var pmc windows.PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
    err = windows.GetProcessMemoryInfo(windows.Handle(handle), &pmc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error getting process RAM usage:", err)
        return
    }
    ramUsage := pmc.WorkingSetSize
```

Please let me know

- if getting CPU usage is properly done
- I can see in error `windows.PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` and `windows.GetProcessMemoryInfo` are undifined. (also verified from the online doc). what should i do/use here to get RAM usage?

Comment: If you want to do this on your own, you need to first define what "ram usage" and "cpu usage" even mean, there's no simple answer. Or you could use an existing package like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3